# Extending xgboost.XGBClassifier

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to define a class called `XGBExtended` that extends the class `xgboost.XGBClassifier`, the scikit-learn API for xgboost.  I am running into some issues with the `get_params` method.  Below is an IPython session illustrating the issue.  Basically, `get_params` seems to only be returning the attributes I define within `XGBExtended.__init__`, and attributes defined during the parent init method (`xgboost.XGBClassifier.__init__`) are ignored.  I am using IPython and running python 2.7.  Full system specs at bottom.

```
In [182]: import xgboost as xgb
     ...: 
     ...: class XGBExtended(xgb.XGBClassifier):
     ...:   def __init__(self, foo):
     ...:     super(XGBExtended, self).__init__()
     ...:     self.foo = foo
     ...: 
     ...: clf = XGBExtended(foo = 1)
     ...: 
     ...: clf.get_params()
     ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-431c4c3f334b> in <module>()
      8 clf = XGBExtended(foo = 1)
      9 
---> 10 clf.get_params()

/Users/andrewhannigan/lib/xgboost/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.pyc in get_params(self, deep)
    188         if isinstance(self.kwargs, dict):  # if kwargs is a dict, update params accordingly
    189             params.update(self.kwargs)
--> 190         if params['missing'] is np.nan:
    191             params['missing'] = None  # sklearn doesn't handle nan. see #4725
    192         if not params.get('eval_metric', True):

KeyError: 'missing'
```

So I've hit an error because 'missing' is not a key in the `params` dict within the `XGBClassifier.get_params` method.  I enter the debugger to poke around:

```
In [183]: %debug
> /Users/andrewhannigan/lib/xgboost/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py(190)get_params()
    188         if isinstance(self.kwargs, dict):  # if kwargs is a dict, update params accordingly
    189             params.update(self.kwargs)
--> 190         if params['missing'] is np.nan:
    191             params['missing'] = None  # sklearn doesn't handle nan. see #4725
    192         if not params.get('eval_metric', True):

ipdb> params
{'foo': 1}
ipdb> self.__dict__
{'n_jobs': 1, 'seed': None, 'silent': True, 'missing': nan, 'nthread': None, 'min_child_weight': 1, 'random_state': 0, 'kwargs': {}, 'objective': 'binary:logistic', 'foo': 1, 'max_depth': 3, 'reg_alpha': 0, 'colsample_bylevel': 1, 'scale_pos_weight': 1, '_Booster': None, 'learning_rate': 0.1, 'max_delta_step': 0, 'base_score': 0.5, 'n_estimators': 100, 'booster': 'gbtree', 'colsample_bytree': 1, 'subsample': 1, 'reg_lambda': 1, 'gamma': 0}
ipdb>
```

As you can see, the `params` contains only the `foo` variable.  However, the object itself contains all of the params defined by `xgboost.XGBClassifier.__init__`.  But for some reason the `BaseEstimator.get_params` method which is called from `xgboost.XGBClassifier.get_params` is only getting the parameters defined explicitly in the `XGBExtended.__init__` method.  Unfortunately, even if I explicitly call `get_params` with `deep = True`, it still does not work correctly:

```
ipdb> super(XGBModel, self).get_params(deep=True)
{'foo': 1}
ipdb>
```

Can anyone tell why this is happening?

System specs:

```
In [186]: print IPython.sys_info()
{'commit_hash': u'1149d1700',
 'commit_source': 'installation',
 'default_encoding': 'UTF-8',
 'ipython_path': '/Users/andrewhannigan/virtualenvironment/nimble_ai/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython',
 'ipython_version': '5.4.1',
 'os_name': 'posix',
 'platform': 'Darwin-14.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit',
 'sys_executable': '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python',
 'sys_platform': 'darwin',
 'sys_version': '2.7.10 (default, Jul  3 2015, 12:05:53) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)]'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is incorrect declaration of child class. 
When you declare the init method only using `foo`, you are overriding the original one. It will not be initialized automatically, even if the base class constructor is supposed to have default values for them.

You should use the following:

```
class XGBExtended(xgb.XGBClassifier):
    def __init__(self, foo, max_depth=3, learning_rate=0.1,
                 n_estimators=100, silent=True,
                 objective="binary:logistic",
                 nthread=-1, gamma=0, min_child_weight=1,
                 max_delta_step=0, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1, colsample_bylevel=1,
                 reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1,
                 base_score=0.5, seed=0, missing=None, **kwargs):

        # Pass the required parameters to super class
        super(XGBExtended, self).__init__(max_depth, learning_rate,
                                            n_estimators, silent, objective,
                                            nthread, gamma, min_child_weight,
                                            max_delta_step, subsample,
                                            colsample_bytree, colsample_bylevel,
                                            reg_alpha, reg_lambda,
scale_pos_weight, base_score, seed, missing, **kwargs)

        # Use other custom parameters
        self.foo = foo
```

After that you will not get any error.

```
clf = XGBExtended(foo = 1)
print(clf.get_params(deep=True))

>>> {'reg_alpha': 0, 'colsample_bytree': 1, 'silent': True, 
     'colsample_bylevel': 1, 'scale_pos_weight': 1, 'learning_rate': 0.1, 
     'missing': None, 'max_delta_step': 0, 'nthread': -1, 'base_score': 0.5, 
     'n_estimators': 100, 'subsample': 1, 'reg_lambda': 1, 'seed': 0, 
     'min_child_weight': 1, 'objective': 'binary:logistic', 
     'foo': 1, 'max_depth': 3, 'gamma': 0}
```

Comment: @andrew I have changed my answer and I'm not getting any error now.

Comment: thanks!  So clearly there is some scikit-learn magic going on with `get_params`.  Does `get_params` look at the signature of the `__init__()` to decide which of the object fields are actual modelling parameters?  A little annoying that you have to restate all of the init arguments of the class you are extending.

Comment: @andrew No, I dont think this is due to scikit. IMO its a python thing actually when you override the init() method, there is no way to find when the actual superclass init is called or not.

Comment: I am still having an issue where `XGBExtended.get_params` is missing some params like `n_jobs` and `random_state`.  Try comparing `XGBExtended().get_params()` to `XGBClassifier().get_params()`.

Comment: @andrew No, its related to the version of xgb. I have 0.6 and I have added parameters in the answer according to that. You need to add all the parameters in the `init()` of XGBExtended which are in your current version of xgboost.